# Is the DLR going to be capable of compiling client-side code?

Tags: .net, dynamic-language-runtime

Is the DLR intended to be used to compile code exclusively prior to distribution or will it potentially be used to compile client-side Javascript in a JIT fashion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CLR already compiles and JITs code, and from what I gather the DLR will be built entirely *on top of* the CLR. So I guess the answer is 'neither'.

Comment: I didn't realize the DLR would be built on top of the CLR. Very interesting.

Comment: I infer, from your information, an answer of..."No the DLR will not be able to JIT clientside javascript code". Is this what you meant?

Upvoted as the answer was useful but not marked as accepted answer as I am unsure if my conclusion is what you meant.

Comment: Reading around the subject of the DLR with the CLR dependancy in mind, it seems that the DLR dynamically creates CLR compatible code and hands that code off to the CLR... fair enough

Comment: Your answer, as I said, seems to suggest a "No".. but I wonder if the DLR couldn't also sit on top of the CLR which allows silverlight to function cross-platform. At this point we are however completely into the realms of guesswork :)